# Laravel [5.3|5.4] testing dispatch of job within a job

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm struggling to understand how I could test a dispatch of a job within another job. I'll provide a code sample.

This is my main job class, we can call it `father`

```
final class FatherJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 */
public function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    \Log::info("Hello World, I'm the father.");

    dispatch(new ChildJob());
}
}
```

Then we have the child job

```
final class ChildJob implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 */
public function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    \Log::info("I'm the child");
}
}
```

The test has been set as following

```
final class JobTest extends TestCase
{
/** @test */
public function it_has_been_dispatched()
{
    $this->expectsJobs(ChildJob::class);
    dispatch(New FatherJob ());
}
}
```

This test fails, of course that's the whole point of the question, but why?

I've done some digging and I presume that the problem relies on the call `withoutJobs()` inside `expectsJobs()`, it seems that `withoutJobs()` distrupt the current queue thus it doesn't allow to call the rest of the jobs but maybe I am totally off track.

If this logic is intended, how can I create a test suite that allows me to check if the job within a job has been called?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

expectsJobs mock all jobs engine.  You can't use dispacth().

```
$this->expectsJobs(ChildJob::class);
$job = new FatherJob();
$job->handle();
```